# is it possible to have a list in the ajax.actionlink routevalues

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an `Ajax.ActionLink` and in the routevalues I have a `new List<object>` is this legal? Also, do I need the `@ before the Model`?

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.LastName[lastNameCount - 1].Value1, // <-- Text to display
   "TimeSeriesData", // <-- Action Method Name
   new List<object>{@Model, @Model.LastName[lastNameCount - 1]},
   new AjaxOptions
      {
         UpdateTargetId = "dialog2", // <-- DOM element ID to update
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
         HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method
      },
   new
      {
         @id = "opener"

      })
```

and my controller method accepts a list as a parameter

mymethod(List List)

Comment: for list model binder read this article http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: ah thats right... the list model binder, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: if its useful you can add up vote to my comment ;)

Comment: I cant, I only have 1 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using `@Ajax.ActionLink()`. If you pass an object, internally the method uses reflection to build a `RouteValueDictionary` using name and value of each property in object. So for a simple object with only primitive projects it might return (say for a Person object) `/TimeSeriesData?id=1&firstname=John&lastname=Doe` but for a collection or a complex object within an object, it only returns the `ToString()` method of the property.

In your case (check the html it generates) it would be something like `/TimeSeriesData?capacity=0&count=0` because `capacity` and `count` are properties of `List`. You could build you own `RouteValueDictionary` but this would not be a good idea since you would quickly exceed the character limit for a query string. Instead just pass the ID of the model, and get the model from the database (or session) again in the action method.

Comment: I see, I was doing that before but my boss didn't like the frequent database calls

Comment: From a performance point of view its far better to pass just an ID and get the object from the database again rather than posting a whole lot of extra data across the wire (passing data from the server to the client and vice versa is always the weak point/bottleneck). If you wan't to avoid calls to the database (usually insignificant anyway) you can always add the object to session and get it from there)